# The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015

First, I've read all the questions regarding the issue.

Yes, I've checked/deleted my `web.config` file in the folder containing the view.

Yes, there are other other views in the same folder with no problems.

Yes, there are other classes in the same namespace with my model's namespace (but regardless of the class, I'm getting this error).

Yes, I've cleaned the solution.

Yes, I've restarted Visual Studio.

Yes, I'm on the latest version (as of writing, 2015, Update 2) of Visual Studio.

No, I'm not doing anything fancy about Razor pages, syntax, web.config etc.

No, I don't have any Visual Studio plugins.

Whatever I try, Visual Studio keeps telling me that *the Model doesn't exist in the current context* only for a particular file. There are other `cshtml` files just as this one in the same folder, many of them have strongly typed models (from the same folder, with the same protection level), and they are all working correctly. The problem exist just at the beginning of the file:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: @CharlesMager can't you see the beginning of the code? please read more carefully, `model` is assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting the question, I've figured out the error. It's due to Visual Studio's poor Razor syntax parsing.

As the `Model` may be null, I was assigning it to a new variable and if it was null, I was creating a new instance (I can't directly assign to `Model` as it's read-only), and the name of the variable was `model`:

```
var model = Model;
if(model == null) {
  model = ...
}
```

Anyway. I was using that `model` instance which was guaranteed to be non-null and have some values. Below, I was using `<meta name="description" content="@model.Description" />` and Razor thought that I was declaring a new model type for the page when it saw `@model`, while the `@` was for escaping into C# and `model` was my variable name. I've changed the varible `model` to `m` (or anything else that wouldn't be a keyword) and the problem went away.

Answer (score 7):

`@model` is a reserved word for specifying the type of the model.

Use `@Model` to get the instance.

In your case simply use another name for your variable.

Answer (score 2):

The solution from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) worked for me:

Run VS as administrator

Then run
`Uninstall-Package -Id Microsoft-Web-Helpers`
followed by:
`Install-Package -Id Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers`